# Access modifiers in C#

Tags: c#, private, access-modifiers

I am teaching myself C# and I have run into a bit of an ambiguous situation.

What I'm trying to do is create a container class for some data, fairly straight forward but I am trying to respect encapsulation and have the data accessible via setters and getters only. So I am reading about access modifiers and according to  [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)  the default access level is Internal. I am from Java-land so I am not familiar with internal, however from the resources on that page, it looks like Internal is more permissive than I want to be. So I want to set things as private.

My confusion arises from the code example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx). it looks like if I do

```
class whatever {
    private int thing;
    string ambiguous; 
}
```

the ambiguous variable will be private, not internal.

Does it actually work like that? Or is the second example mis-written?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The field `ambiguous` is not ambiguous at all. The C# specification states that in the absence of an access modifier on **a class member** it defaults to `private`.

The default access level **on top-level types** is internal.

```
class Foo {
    int bar;
    class Nested {
        int baz;
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
internal class Foo {
    private int bar;
    private class Nested {
        private int baz;
    }
}
```

Comment: In case it isn't clear, the default access level *on top-level types* is internal. Nested types default to private. The spec considers nested types to be static class members.